# When I add alert('now it works'); this function works but I don't want this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I add alert('now it works'); this function works when I remove this alert its not work, but I don't want this alert.

```
function a() {
    var ac = document.forms["myForm"]["textfield"].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'z.php?ac=' + ac,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'ok') {
                alert('ok');
            }
            else {
                alert('year already exits');
            }
        },
    });
    alert('now it works');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? What happens when it doesn't work? (Are you having problems structuring asynchronous code or something? Note that the comma after the `}` on the fourth last line will break the code in some browsers.)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Could you show how you are using the function?

Comment: The alert can't be the issue.

Comment: I suspect you are doing this inside a form ...the alert is temporarily blocking the form submit. Without it the page is reloading. Use `event.preventDefault()` to stop form submitting

Comment: Replace it with document.write('');

Answer (score 0):

You might read the value of the input field by using a jQuery's [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for the field.

Then simply append the value to the URL.
It's a GET request.

```
   function a() {         
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'z.php?ac=' + $("#myInputfield").val(),            
        success: function(data){
           console.log('it works. data: ' + data);
        }
      });
    }
```

This is not the best way to do this: please look into jQuery Ajax Post & Form Serialization.

Instead of alert() you might use console.log(). Alert might block the Ajax execution.